# how can I change a value indside a map of maps?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a map of a string and a map, and I want to change a value inside the inner map but I couldn't find a method to do that. How can I reach and change the specific value inside the inner map?

here's my maps:

```
String teamName;

Map<String, Integer> players = new HashMap<String,Integer>();   

Map<String, Map> teams = new HashMap<String, Map>();

teams.put(teamName, players);
```

I want to increase or decrease this integer value inside the players map from the teams map. But I cannot use the players map directly because of the rest of my code, I need to reach it from the teams map.

Comment: So there is only one map inside the outer map -- what are you modeling with this?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is access the appropriate team's map, then set the number.

It will help if you used generics throughout:

```
String teamName = "someteam";
Map<String, Integer> players = new HashMap<String,Integer>();   
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> teams = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>>();
teams.put(teamName, players);
```

And to change the number of players in team with `teamName` as key:

```
teams.get(teamName).put("somename", 123);
//Or to directly overwrite with an increment:
int currentValue = teams.get(teamName).get("somename");
teams.get(teamName).put("somename", currentValue + 1);
```

Comment: Nice answer ;) But can't you simplify your second and third line to just `... = new HashMap<>()`?

Comment: @PauloMattos: Could do that, but that would be assuming that the user is building with Java 7+. But agreed, that would be better.

Answer (score 0):

with the map put and get can be tricky, you should define yyour own class, but this is ans example of what you are asking:

```
Map<String, Integer> players = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> teams = new HashMap<>();

players.put("Podolski", 0);
players.put("mueller", 0);

teams.put("BayernMuc", players);

System.out.println(players);
System.out.println(teams);
int goals = teams.get("BayernMuc").get("mueller");
teams.get("BayernMuc").put("mueller", 5);

System.out.println(teams);
goals = teams.get("BayernMuc").get("mueller");
teams.get("BayernMuc").put("mueller", ++goals);
System.out.println(players);
System.out.println(teams);
```